# Chemical Package in ConTeXt broken?

Tags: context

I'm using context version 2020.01.30 14:13

The context garden wiki example

```
\usemodule[chemic]
\startformula
 \chemical{2H_2,+,O_2,->,2H_2O}
\stopformula
```

yields

[image]

and taking it apart:

```
\startformula
\chemical{C} \chemical{+} \chemical{O_2} \chemical{GIVES} \chemical{CO_2}
\stopformula
```

yields a defective version too. (lowered C)

[image]

Is there a working way to type chemical formulae using the chemic package?

As suggested in a comment: removing chemic and using

```
\startchemicalformula
 \chemical{2H_2,+,O_2,->,2H_2O}
\stopchemicalformula
```

still yields

[image]

using

```
\startchemicalformula
\chemical{C} \chemical{+} \chemical{O_2} \chemical{GIVES} \chemical{CO_2}
\stopchemicalformula
```

works somewhat but has a much too small font-size

[image]

Comment: `chemic` is no longer needed. The syntax as it appears in the sources suggest you should use `\startchemicalformula ... \stopchemicalformula`

Comment: I am not sure the chemistry "has a much too small font-size", I'd rather suspect that you need to setup your fonts differently. It would help, if you could post how your math and sans font is setup.